# PHP curl_exec() not working online but works fine on localhost as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS not attaching data to http post request

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, dns

I cannot figure out why this code works locally on my PC (localhost) but not online on google app-engine? Can it be a PHP version issue ?

```
<?php

include_once 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';


function curl_exec_follow($ch, &$maxredirect = null) {


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
$mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    if ($mr > 0)
    {
        $original_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $newurl = $original_url;

        $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);

        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
        do
        {
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);

            $header = curl_exec($rch);
            if (curl_errno($rch)) {
                $code = 0;
            } else {
                $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
                    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/i', $header, $matches);
                    $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));

                    // if no scheme is present then the new url is a
                    // relative path and thus needs some extra care
                    if(!preg_match("/^https?:/i", $newurl)){
                        $newurl = $original_url . $newurl;
                    }
                } else {
                    $code = 0;
                }
            }
        } while ($code && --$mr);

        curl_close($rch);

        if (!$mr)
        {
            if ($maxredirect === null)
                trigger_error('Too many redirects.', E_USER_WARNING);
            else
                $maxredirect = 0;

            return false;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    }
  return curl_exec($ch);
}
    function getContentofEgov( $egovid, $birthdate, $examtype, $currentsem) {
    $batchyear="";

    $cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";   
    if(file_exists($cookie_file_path))
        unlink($cookie_file_path);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "LoginForm[username]=".$egovid."&LoginForm[password]=".$birthdate."");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    // provides warning on gae
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php?r=site/login');  
    $output1 = curl_exec_follow($ch);

    echo $output1;

    if(!empty($output1)){
    $scraped_data = str_get_html($output1);
        if(!empty($scraped_data)){
    $table =$scraped_data->find('table',1) ;
            if(!empty($table)){
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $key=>$value){
        if((trim(strip_tags($value->find('th',0)->plaintext)))== "Batch Year"){
            //echo trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',0)));
            $batchyear= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',0)->plaintext));
            echo $batchyear;
        }

        if((trim(strip_tags($value->find('th',0)->plaintext)))== "Old Student Code"){

            $username= substr(trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',0)->plaintext)),-5);
        }

    }
            }}}
    else{

        return "Internal Server Error.";
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php?r=tblstudentmst/academicHistory');
    $output2 = curl_exec_follow($ch);
    echo $output2;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sessionno=".$currentsem."&batchyear=".$batchyear."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php?r=tblstudentmst/'.$examtype.'Relational');
    $output3 = curl_exec_follow($ch);
    echo $output3;
    if(file_exists($cookie_file_path))
        unlink($cookie_file_path);


    return $output3;



}
```

It is not giving any output.I've also tried to get error from curl_error() but it is not returning anything.I tried to come up with the solution but couldn't find anything.please help.

By enabling curlopt_verbose i got :

```
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 203.88.131.36...
* Connected to egov.ddit.ac.in (203.88.131.36) port 80 (#0)
> POST /index.php?r=site/login HTTP/1.1
Host: egov.ddit.ac.in
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5)            Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 61
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 61 out of 61 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 19:52:36 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
* Added cookie PHPSESSID="r5ndtpkqje5tq1cgmr85pcop90" for domain egov.ddit.ac.in, path /, expire 0 
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=r5ndtpkqje5tq1cgmr85pcop90; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
* Replaced cookie PHPSESSID="9n2ng1cufjg5sc5trcisoartn6" for domain egov.ddit.ac.in, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9n2ng1cufjg5sc5trcisoartn6; path=/
< Location: http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host egov.ddit.ac.in left intact
```

It seems postfields are not set in there. I'm stuck into these. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the application logs? Are you usig curl_lite or curl.so?

Comment: curl.so @StuartLangley

Comment: Not at all a PHP expert, but after php5, isn't it suggested to use "http_build_query"? Maybe you could try that, or try putting all your params in an array instead of a string?

Comment: @Patrice also tried it after reading it in the other posts but got no difference :(

Comment: There are no errors in your application logs in your dev console? If you go to console.developers.google.com and try to check under "monitoring->logs" right after you've tried the curl, there is no logs at all?

Comment: @Patrice No errors there. In localhost everything works fine but after deployment, curl() is not working i guess and neither throwing any errors

Comment: With no errors, but still blank? Feels weird. Do you mind giving out the URL? I will try to see if it is possible to reproduce your issue. Because if your devserver (your local machine) can hit the URL and once deployed the App Engine can't, then yeah it might be restricted on the server somehow

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to two reasons:

1. you never installed php-curl on live server.
2. particular URL restricted on that server.

Comment: also url is not restricted.